# Is there a way to filter a dimension based on the value of another field?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm building a data dashboard for a project and I want to be able to compare data from two distinct groups in the same dataset.

My dataset looks like this:

```
Number,Name,Gender,Race,Height,Publisher,Alignment,Weight,Superpower,Strength,Costume Colour
1,A-Bomb,Male,Metahuman,203,Marvel Comics,Good,441,Superhuman Strength,10,None
2,Abin Sur,Male,Alien,185,DC Comics,Good,90,Cosmic Power,40,Green
3,Abomination,Male,Metahuman,203,Marvel Comics,Bad,441,Superhuman Strength,10,None
4,Abraxas,Male,Cosmic Entity,1000,Marvel Comics,Bad,1000,Reality Warping,40,Green
5,Absorbing Man,Male,Metahuman,193,Marvel Comics,Bad,122,Matter Duplication,5,None
6,Adam Strange,Male,Human,185,DC Comics,Good,88,None,0,Red
```

I want to create two separate `selectMenus` which list the character names, but with each of the two menus filtered on `Publisher` name.

So one drop down will have all the characters associated with `Marvel Comics`, and the other will have all the characters associated with `DC Comics`.

Once this is set up, the idea is that the dashboard can then show a set of graphs which work as a comparison between the two characters that have been selected - so I don't want the entire dataset to be split out, I just want the selection to be filtered by Publisher.

I've been through dozens of different Stack Overflow threads about similar stuff but still struggling. I've created the dimensions for character name and character publisher but I'm getting really lost trying to use one to filter the other.

This is what I've got so far (ignore the costume color stuff, that's for something further down the line) - the data in 'heroes-information.csv' is in the same format I shared above.

```
// Bring in data from csv files

Promise.all([d3.csv("../data/heroes-information.csv"), d3.csv("../data/costume-colors.csv")])
    .then(function(data) {

        // Tidy data before use

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.Height = +d.Height;
            d.Weight = +d.Weight;
            d.Strength = +d.Strength;
        });

        // Bring in Heroes data

        var ndx = crossfilter(data[0]);

        // Bring in costume color data

        var ndxcol = crossfilter(data[1]);

        // Create colorScale to dynamically color pie chat slices

        var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(data[1].map(row => row.Name))
            .range(data[1].map(row => row.RGB));

        // Define chart type

        var dccomicsSelector = dc.selectMenu('#dccomics-selector');

        // Define chart dimension

        var character = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('Name'));
        var characterPublisher = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('Publisher'));

        var dccomicsCharacters = character.group();
        var dccomicsPublisher = characterPublisher.group();

        dccomicsSelector
            .dimension(character)
            .group(dccomicsCharacters);


        dc.renderAll();

    });
```

I'm probably missing something really obvious but I'm fairly new to DC.js and Crossfilter so a bit lost in the weeds with this one, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Crossfilter doesn't directly support multiple filter sets - there's just one active filter at a time. (Partly an efficiency hack.) I think are probably ways to do what you want but there is going to be some coding and going outside the system.

Comment: Thanks for this Gordon, good to know I wasn't just going mad and not being able to find the answer. I have reconfigured my project slightly by splitting out the dataset into 2, one for Marvel and one for DC, and will work on combining the data to build the charts in dc.js instead.

Comment: If you don't need to aggregate across multiple publishers, that may be a lot easier. Typically each "chart group" (second parameter to chart constructors) corresponds to a crossfilter instance with its own dataset.